# All expected conditions written in fixture.whenStable().then are populating as SPEC HAS NO EXPECTATIONS

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-material, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have few expectations written under fixture.whenStable().then() in an async environment.
If I remove the fixture.whenStable().then() and place expected conditions outside my tests are failing even after mentioning fixture.detectChanges(). Is there any way to avoid the **SPEC HAS NO EXPECTATIONS**.

```
  it('save & remaining feilds should be enabled if employee currently employeed', async(() => {
    let employee1 = new Employee();
    employee1.id = 1;
    employee1.name = "Vineel pellella";
    employee1.workLocation = "Hyderabad";
    employee1.email = "vineel.royal@gmail.com";
    employee1.contactNo = 9985896040;
    employee1.dateOfBirth = new Date().toDateString();
    employee1.dateOfJoining = new Date().toDateString();
    
    component.emp = employee1;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      expect(fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector("#empId").disabled).toBe(false);
      expect(fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector("#empName").disabled).toBe(false);
      expect(fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector("#dateOfBirth").disabled).toBe(false);
      expect(fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector("#designation").disabled).toBe(false);
      
      expect(fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector("#dateOfJoining").disabled).toBe(false);
      expect(fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector("#workLocation").disabled).toBe(false);
      
      expect(fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector("#inputGroupSelect01").disabled).toBe(false);
      expect(fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector("#contactNumber").disabled).toBe(false);
      expect(fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector("#email").disabled).toBe(false);
      expect(fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector("#dateOfLeaving").disabled).toBeFalsy();
      expect(fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector("#save").disabled).toBeFalsy();
    });
  }));
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the code inside of the `fixture.whenStable` is never ran meaning a promise is most likely hanging (not resolving) in the code.

Try changing the test to the below code:

```
it('save & remaining feilds should be enabled if employee currently employeed', async () => { // add regular async here
    let employee1 = new Employee();
    employee1.id = 1;
    employee1.name = "Vineel pellella";
    employee1.workLocation = "Hyderabad";
    employee1.email = "vineel.royal@gmail.com";
    employee1.contactNo = 9985896040;
    employee1.dateOfBirth = new Date().toDateString();
    employee1.dateOfJoining = new Date().toDateString();
    
    component.emp = employee1;
    fixture.detectChanges();
    await fixture.whenStable();
    expect(1).toBe(1);
});
```

If you get a timeout error, it means `await fixture.whenStable()` is never resolving meaning that there is a promise in your component code that is not resolving.